# Regex on list element in for loop

Tags: python

I have a script that searches through config files and finds all matches of strings from another list as follows:

```
dstn_dir = "C:/xxxxxx/foobar"
dst_list =[]
files = [fn for fn in os.listdir(dstn_dir)if fn.endswith('txt')]
dst_list = []
for file in files:
    parse = CiscoConfParse(dstn_dir+'/'+file)
    for sfarm in search_str:
        int_objs = parse.find_all_children(sfarm)
        if len(int_objs) > 0:
            dst_list.append(["\n","#" *40,file + " " + sfarm,"#" *40])
            dst_list.append(int_objs)
```

I need to change this part of the code:

```
 for sfarm in search_str:
            int_objs = parse.find_all_children(sfarm)
```

`search_str` is a list containing strings similar to `['xrout:55','old:23']` and many others.

So it will only find entries that end with the string from the list I am iterating through in `sfarm`.  My understanding is that this would require my to use `re` and match on something like `sfarm$` but Im not sure on how to do this as part of the loop.

Am I correct in saying that `sfarm` is an iterable?  If so I need to know how to regex on an iterable object in this context.

Comment: You forgot to include the definition of `search_str`, so it's hard to say what `sfarm` is. In other words, see ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `search_str` is the iterable and `sfarm` is a normal element (that may be iterable too) of your list on which you can use regex

Comment: IIja Everila and me wants to know how search_str will populated and from where? More, it will be good if you can add sample data that can be search_str.

Comment: if you only wants to check that a string ends with a substring, you do not need regular expression, the endswith method of string should be enough: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.endswith#str.endswith

Comment: Updated as per @Ilja Everilä note.

Comment: As @DineshPundkar pointed out you could simplify greatly your file handling with either the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module or if using python 3 [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) module's globbing features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in python are iterable, so `sfarm` is an iterable, but that has little meaning in this case. From reading what [`CiscoConfParse.find_all_children()`](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_CiscoConfParse.html#ciscoconfparse.CiscoConfParse.find_all_children) does, it is apparent that your `sfarm` is the `linespec`, which is a regular expression string. You do not need to explicitly use the `re` module here; just pass `sfarm` concatenated with `'$'`:

```
search_string = ['xrout:55','old:23']
...
for sfarm in search_str:
    int_objs = parse.find_all_children(sfarm + '$')  # one of many ways to concat
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson and simple effective solution.  I have accepted this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. Used glob module to get all "*.txt" files in folder.

Please check here for more info on [glob module](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/).

```
import glob
import re
dst_list = []
search_str = ['xrout:55','old:23']
for file_name in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/dinesh_pundkar\Desktop/*.txt'):
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        for sfarm in search_str:
            regex = re.compile('%s$'%sfarm)
            int_objs = regex.findall(text)
            if len(int_objs) > 0:
                dst_list.append(["\n","#" *40,file_name + " " + sfarm,"#" *40])
                dst_list.append(int_objs)
print dst_list
```

Output:

```
 C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python a.py
[['\n', '########################################', 'C:/Users/dinesh_pundkar\\De
sktop\\out.txt old:23', '########################################'], ['old:23']]

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: Marking this answer up as per suggestion to use glob, thanks